# how to run javascript code through iframe tag of html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

i want to run javascript code over an iframe tag of html5.

this is my code for iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i6Rdkv-DLwk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Iframe is not for just js. And I dont recommend you doing it since it is useless. Iframe is anyways encapsulated. What reason do you want it for?

Comment: i have 5 vidoes in my page and one progress bar, i have to run the progress bar when user clicks on the play button of the video player.

Comment: That needs angular and not iframe. There are quite a few examples for you to start with. Capture the video play event and then notify the progress bar. A example of a quiz application is linked. `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_playing.asp` `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774833/angular-progress-bar-controller` `http://www.angularjs4u.com/loading/5-angularjs-loadingprogress-bar-options/ ` `https://hungryturtlecode.com/code-projects/angular-quiz-app/10-ng-class/`